# Displaying very large numbers, represented by byte[]

Tags: c++, c, math, integer, bit-manipulation

This is a bit of an absurd question that I've had on my mind for a while, but let's say I want to display a very, very, large number, one that cannot be represented by a normal primitive (or combination of primitives... no `long long ...`s), so I suppose a byte array  in memory could be used.

If I have a byte array of n-bytes (where n is something large) length, how can I print the byte array out correctly, as if it is an integer in base 10 decimal. An explanation instead of just an answer would be preferred.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using a preexisting bignum library?

Comment: Do you want to print it in binary, octal, hexadecimal, decimal, base-(-2), etc etc?

Comment: @KevinBallard just because I want to know

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze base 10 decimal

Comment: "just because I want to know" .. so *try* something first. I recommend starting with displaying an `int` to sdtout using a *custom function*. Then it should just be reasonable step from there to move from `int` to span a sequence of "bytes" following a given encoding (it is actually a bit more work, but a base has been established). If still stuck, *after* doing this initial `int` -> stdout attempt, a better question will emerge. Hint: process each "byte" with a carry-over.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (to implement and understand) would be to divide the number repeatedly by 10, collecting the remainders, example:

1234 / 10 = 123, 4
123 / 10 = 12, 3
12 / 10 = 1, 2
1 / 10 = 0, 1

Then you print the remainders (in the reverse order).

When dividing the sequence of bytes by 10 you divide each byte individually, starting with the most significant byte. And you carry the remainder from the division to the next byte until you've processed all bytes.

```
int divBytesBy10(unsigned char* bytes, size_t count, unsigned char* remainder)
{
  unsigned carryOver = 0;
  int nonZeroQuotient = 0;

  while (count--)
  {
    carryOver = carryOver * 256 + *bytes;
    *bytes = carryOver / 10;
    carryOver %= 10;

    nonZeroQuotient |= *bytes++;
  }

  *remainder = carryOver;
  return nonZeroQuotient;
}
```

A full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divBytesBy10(unsigned char* bytes, size_t count, unsigned char* remainder)
{
  unsigned carryOver = 0;
  int nonZeroQuotient = 0;

  while (count--)
  {
    carryOver = carryOver * 256 + *bytes;
    *bytes = carryOver / 10;
    carryOver %= 10;

    nonZeroQuotient |= *bytes++;
  }

  *remainder = '0' + carryOver; // convert to ASCII right here
  return nonZeroQuotient;
}

int main(void)
{
  unsigned char num[] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
  char str[11], *p = str + sizeof(str) - 1;
  *p = '\0';
  while (divBytesBy10(num, sizeof(num), --p)) {}
  printf("%s\n", p);
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/GZu4Z)):

```
4294967295
```